# Get last messages from table ordered by created_at

Tags: mysql, activerecord, yii2, mariadb

Maybe it's something continuous question, but I need little help.
I have a table

```
CREATE TABLE `ticket_message` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ticket_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `message` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `created_at` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `updated_at` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_flag` tinyint(2) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

I just need to get last messages,
example:

Here it is:

```
'57', '26', 'Hello\r\n', '1474019653', '1474019653', '0'
'58', '26', 'Where is my order?', '1474019672', '1474019672', '0'
'59', '27', 'Hi', '1474019824', '1474019824', '0'
'60', '28', 'Hi\r\n', '1474019921', '1474019921', '0'
'61', '28', 'Where is my item?', '1474019933', '1474019933', '0'
'62', '26', 'Hello', '1474019983', '1474019983', '1'
'63', '26', 'Hello', '1474020069', '1474020069', '0'
'64', '26', 'fdsfdsfds', '1474020191', '1474020191', '1'
'65', '26', 'fdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfs', '1474020256', '1474020256', '0'
'66', '26', 'fdsfsfsfdsfs', '1474020358', '1474020358', '0'
'67', '27', 'hello', '1474020872', '1474020872', '1'
'68', '27', 'how are you', '1474020953', '1474020953', '0'
'69', '27', 'okey', '1474020963', '1474020963', '0'
'70', '29', 'This is a test message', '1474021973', '1474021973', '0'
'71', '29', 'This is also a test message', '1474023004', '1474023004', '1'
'72', '30', 'Test  message', '1474025254', '1474025254', '0'
'73', '30', 'Test Reply Message', '1474025473', '1474025473', '1'
'74', '28', '123', '1475166801', '1475166801', '1'
'75', '27', 'foo\r\n', '1475167415', '1475167415', '1'
```

I just want a query, maybe "raw", maybe "yii2", that return me

1. Test Reply Message
2. foo
3. fdsfsfsfdsfs
4. This is also a test message
5. 123

Comment: Are you looking for a raw query or something using the `yii2` framework?

Comment: it's not big deal, just a little mind to help me, to do this query, it's maybe a raw.
just "groupBy", "limit 1", or something else.
I just want to get last   `message` by created_at

Comment: Which column should determine the "first" record?  `id` or the time?

Comment: I don't need "first" record, I need something like `SELECT * 
FROM
  (
    SELECT *
    FROM `ticket_message` 
    ORDER BY updated_at DESC
  ) as `new_table`
GROUP BY `ticket_id` `

but it don't work like I need, it return me first, but I need **last**

Comment: in mysql 5.6 it works, but not in mariadb,
all servers that I config, works on mariadb and this query return _first_ not _last_ message in this table

Comment: I was considering helping until I saw `f**k`, then I lost interest.

Comment: This f****, It was QA help, to show me the problem, sorry if it's hurts your thin feelings, nothing personal. 
It's just, "lorem ipsum"

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM ticket_message
    ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 5;
```

If the framework won't let you say that, the fie on them.

(`GROUP BY` is not appropriate.)
(Subqueries are not required.)